# TypeScript: Restricts arguments of a function

Tags: typescript

could someone give me a hint on how to restrict the valid arguments of the function `getMessage`:

```
type Translations = {
    readonly [key: string]: Localize;
}

interface Localize {
    readonly "en": string,
    readonly "de"?: string,
    readonly "fr"?: string
}

const translationsObj: Translations = {
    "keyOne": { "en":"one", "de":"eins" },
    "keyTwo": { "en":"two", "de":"zwei" }
};

type TranslationKeys = keyof typeof translationsObj; // = string | number

function getMessage(key: TranslationKeys) {
    return translationsObj[key]["de"];
}

const msg1 = getMessage("keyOne"); // OK
const msg2 = getMessage("notAPropOfTranslationsObj"); // should be marked as error
```

Only the properties of the object `translationsObj` should be allowed to be passed.

Roland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use Typescript 4.9 beta, you could use the `satisfies` operator; it does exactly what you want.

```
type Translations = {
    readonly [key: string]: Localize;
}

interface Localize {
    readonly "en": string,
    readonly "de"?: string,
    readonly "fr"?: string
}

const translationsObj = {
    "keyOne": { "en":"one", "de":"eins" },
    "keyTwo": { "en":"two", "de":"zwei" }
} satisfies Translations;

type TranslationKeys = keyof typeof translationsObj; // = string | number

function getMessage(key: TranslationKeys) {
    return translationsObj[key]["de"];
}

const msg1 = getMessage("keyOne"); // OK
const msg2 = getMessage("notAPropOfTranslationsObj"); // error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcA2DgEsD2qoC8UA3gLABQUVUcECAJnmiFANoDWEIAXFCsHCxIA5gF1eAGRwBjBGiwAvCAG4KAXwoUhwCHABmCadCmz5SkhWo06jJMygAiCEge9%20gkQBpL1WgyYsDvQQDgD8bgJCwt6UvjYBjnpwYREewuqa5NJ4-FACyOiYuKgA8gBGAFaEFrFUDpwgJUghvMSOzq4OeCGejsGdEEIoDlBqMVb1XDAA7jiuJO0u3A7Asw69QS0OCtODIxrkanxFKHpYECiwiKgY2Dmq5BSgkFcFt8UA0lyXRA04enlwBB-nlroU7qVKsooAB6GHVdxRKAAHygSAArgBbMq6TJ6dFIaQQqDCCDAACyFxQCFJAAoGrx4G8ingviAUABKGpWWjAdFwJCg5kQlDlCocLiiVibByiB4HCjZVDAKCYlDCACM1VJFKpNIgtMmjWaDg50LhUBKH0VORVauEACZtWTKShqXSHEgcMAAIIABTgODAJT0TJuLMhFVN5vhukDcCAA)

Comment: Ooh, good to know and very useful. I've had to work around this so much, this would make things a lot easier.

Comment: That works great with Typescript 4.9 beta, that's what I was looking for, thanks Akxe.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `Translations` type. By defining it as a map, you're basically saying its keys are unbounded and can be any string.

Instead, just define it in terms of what keys are available and create a record out of that.

```
type TranslationKeys = "keyOne" | "keyTwo";

const translationsObj: Record<TranslationKeys, Localize> = {
    "keyOne": { "en":"one", "de":"eins" },
    "keyTwo": { "en":"two", "de":"zwei" }
};

function getMessage(key: TranslationKeys) {
    return translationsObj[key]["de"];
}

const msg1 = getMessage("keyOne"); // OK
const msg2 = getMessage("notAPropOfTranslationsObj"); // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-NAjVAyEA)

---

On the other hand, if you have a lot of keys you map out, then you might want to create a helper function to get the right types.

```
const translations = <T extends { [key: string]: Localize }>(t: T) => t as Record<keyof T, Localize>;

const translationsObj = translations({
    "keyOne": { "en":"one", "de":"eins" },
    "keyTwo": { "en":"two", "de":"zwei" }
});

type TranslationKeys = keyof typeof translationsObj;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsFwDbAF4oDeAsAFDIXJQRwAm6I2AnsgEQQisBcyAzmFFABzADRlKVGvUYtWtCKwD8PfoJCjxlanQbM2MKEpUDhZAL5kyCBv2QC4IXtjhhgN5AF5kAHgAqyCAAPSBBaXmRCZABtAGsIJmM1IQBdHgwsXAJkMwA+AAowHl8ASk8cu2Q4cIAlCGsoWm84pnQYZF8RNEwcfAgcgG5LUmtHMDsoBycXN0cAeQAjACtPccnnVxs8knJKVmbZkAUeSPZOLlYGBU65I-ZQXlZssR2KPfjfAHd0bgi2Dm5WGAvqxrvIAXgPhBgI8LKQzMVBqQyGAmAAHFC+CaOdYzADS8XCXmarTsaIgJPs2OmNgWi0RZBgAFcQAgNiBkEIIGAALIQXi8OCcvLNIpYqZs-FMXilbYSahgRlQdmU8UzXi02LxZJRG6sZKI2FWGxjAC2vCEAEYVpyeXyBUK3kwDgoEcgAPRu5CzXFG0bIM1CABM1q5vP5gogeVYIHQYAAggAFKDoVGzGCYtbUuZLViuj18AAW6EZ2FoyHmKBNcCgcTLVQCUGTUDIQA)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jeff. So I have to write the keys twice, right? There will be many more properties in the object `translationsObj`. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: In that case, you'll need a helper function to help build the type.

Comment: I'll have a look at it too, thanks!

Comment: Good job with that helper function